# Run external program instead of builtin

Tags: bash, shell, built-in

For example, sometimes I would like to run `/bin/kill` instead of the builtin `kill`. Is this best done as

```
env kill
```

or simply

```
/bin/kill
```

or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be looking the builtin `enable`.  Saying `enable -n kill` would disable the builtin `kill`.

Say `enable kill` in order to enable it again.

The manual gives more information on [Shell Builtin Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands).

Comment: Did not know, there existed a command called `enable`...

Comment: @anishsane `enable` isn't a command; it is a `bash` builtin.

Comment: And what's the difference between command and builtin when it is not an external command?

Comment: You would know it better, won't you @fedorqui

Comment: I have to confess that I don't. I think a builtin as something like `cd`, `ls`, etc, while an external command could be `seq`, `sar`, etc. Am I right on that?

Comment: Say `enable -p` to see the list of builtins enabled by your shell.  You'll notice that there are some like `echo`, `kill` which are both available as builtins and external commands.  BTW, `ls` isn't a builtin.

Comment: Impressing! That goes directly to my list of commands to know and use. Thanks, @devnull.

Answer (score 1):

You want that a simple call to command `kill` should call `/bin/kill` & not the shell built-in.

There are 2 more options (in addition to what is specified by devnull's answer.):

You can alias `kill` to `/bin/kill`.

Or declare a function `kill`, which internally calls `/bin/kill`.