# in Linux "which source" returns nothing?

Tags: c, linux, shell, system-calls

I want to `source` some shell scripts in `c` using `exec()`.

What is `source` ? is that a `binary executable` or a `shell script` ? where can i find that in linux file system ?

I ran

```
charan@PC-113:~$ which source 

charan@PC-113:~$
```

Comment: `source` is an operator in bash. A lot like `>`. http://ss64.com/bash/source.html

Comment: You cannot really `source` from `exec` functions.... (you could `exec` some `/bin/sh` doing the `source`). Either `exec` won't return (on success), or you'll run it in a `fork`-ed child process, and the sourced commands cannot affect your program. You should explain what you really want to do and why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a builtin shell command, like `cd`, `exit`, `pwd`...:

```
$ enable -p | grep source
enable source
```

Note that `enable -p` shows all the builtins. More info in [enable Man page](http://ss64.com/bash/enable.html).

#### Update

Just saw a pretty interesting thread in SuperUser: [What does source do?](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)

```
$ type source
source is a shell builtin
```

#### Update 2 - comment by [Tony D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487514/in-linux-which-source-returns-nothing/17487554#comment25419789_17487554)

> @SIGSEGV: sometimes a command can be implemented as an external
>   (non-shell) executable, but some shells will still want to provide
>   their own implementation... possibly with different behaviour,
>   possibly just to make it faster. test and pwd are examples of this.
>   For example, the shell can get its current working directory using
>   getcwd(), but if it runs a separate executable without changing the
>   current directory for that executable, and the executable runs
>   getcwd() - it still works.

Comment: Had no idea about enable, +1.

Comment: Thanks! I just discovered it [two days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443108/run-external-program-instead-of-builtin/17443378#comment25341156_17443378) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ans, But some of commands like `test`, `pwd` has got executables in `/usr/bin` and they are also in `enable` output

Comment: Good point, @SIGSEGV, I just found out a related thread in [su] that may help as well: http://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do

Comment: @fedorqui that was useful but didn't answer ma last comment :(

Comment: @SIGSEGV: sometimes a command can be implemented as an external (non-shell) executable, but some shells will still want to provide their own implementation... possibly with different behaviour, possibly just to make it faster. `test` and `pwd` are examples of this.  For example, the shell can get its current working directory using `getcwd()`, but if it runs a separate executable without changing the current directory for that executable, and the executable runs `getcwd()` - it still works.

Comment: @TonyD, your comment gives such valuable info. If you dont' mind, I add it to my answer. Feel free to edit it or even remove it from my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can think [source](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) as `.` operator in linux.